# Print a nicely formatted table using (x, x*x, x*x*x)

Tags: python, format

I ran the code below and got syntax error. Have no idea what's wrong.

```
for x in range(1,11):
    print '{0:2d} {1:3d}{2:4d}'.format(x), (x*x), (x*x*x)
```

Comment: I don't. I get an `IndexError` instead.

Comment: If you are really getting a `SyntaxError` here, then you must be using Python 3 and `print()` is a function. That is to say, *apart* from the `IndexError` your code will raise.

Comment: Just as a recommendation: [PrettyTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be `IndexError`:

```
>>> for x in range(1,11):
...     print '{0:2d} {1:3d}{2:4d}'.format(x), (x*x), (x*x*x)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thanks @Martijn Pieters, get it with py3 or `from __future__ import print_function`.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> for x in range(1,11):
...     print '{0:2d} {1:3d}{2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print '{0:2d} {1:3d}{2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You incorrectly pass arguments, try (if print is a function):

```
>>> for x in range(1,11):
...     print('{0:2d} {1:3d} {2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x))
...
 1   1    1
 2   4    8
 3   9   27
 4  16   64
 5  25  125
 6  36  216
 7  49  343
 8  64  512
 9  81  729
10 100 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You need closing and opening parenthesis in `format`:

```
for x in range(1,11):
    print '{0:2d} {1:3d}{2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x)
```

Your code

```
print '{0:2d} {1:3d}{2:4d}'.format(x), (x*x), (x*x*x)
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
print ('{0:2d} {1:3d}{2:4d}'.format(x)), (x*x), (x*x*x)
```

So, you're passing just one value to the format string(i.e just `x`) while it expects 3.

```
>>> '{}{}{}'.format(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    '{}{}{}'.format(1)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If that format string has just one format specifier then your code would've worked properly. This works because **comma separated items** are printed with a space between them:

```
>>> print '{:04d}'.format(1), 2, 3
0001 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want :

```
print '{0:2d} {1:3d} {2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x)
```

format() expects 3 values with the way your format your strings